# how can I compare 3 different columns of data in 3 different worksheets and highlight them in excel 2007?

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet-function

so I have two worksheets with data, I want to compare column A of worksheet 1 to column A of worksheet 2 . Worksheet 1 is a template  and worksheet 2 is a data report. Column A for both worksheets are item #s, worksheet 1 updates item #s and data from the report in worksheet 2. I want to create a formula or I guess vba code (I know nothing about VBA) whatever I can that will compare the item#s. I want the formula/code to pull the data from the report in worksheet 2 to the corresponding item #s in the template of worksheet 1 and high light any new item #s in the report(column A) of worksheet 2 that are not in worksheet 1 and then add those new high lighted item #s and its data to worksheet 1.

The range of data in column A of worksheet 1 is less than the range of data in column A of worksheet 2 that im trying to compare and pull from.

I thought about creating a IF formula in worksheet 2 to show me which item number exist, which are new but because the range of data in column A of worksheet 1 is less than column A of worksheet 2 I end getting an error value,  I think creating a vba may be better but im not sure . Any advice,  please give step by step detail/image of what to do. So far in general for the template I have a vlookup to pull the data BUT I need to know which items are new and highlight/pull them. Also if I could either delete or label the items numbers that is discontinued as discontinued that would be great. I think so far when I do a vlookup the items that are in worksheet 1 and not worksheet 2 come up as #N/A are the discontinued items. I have excel 2007, I hope you can help.

**Sample Sheet1 and Sheet2**

[image][image]

**Output after updating using `Vlookup`**

[image]
I am trying to compare three different columns of data in three worksheets and highlight the differences using VBA. I am very new to VBA and I don't know a lot about programming. So far this is what I've done:

`worksheet1`:

```
Sub compare_cols()
 Dim myRng As Range
 Dim lastCell As Long
 'Get the last row
 Dim lastRow As Integer
 lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
 'Debug.Print "Last Row is " & lastRow
 Dim c As Range
 Dim d As Range
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 For Each c In Worksheets("worksheet1").Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Cells
 For Each d In Worksheets("worksheet2").Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Cells
 c.Interior.Color = vbGreen
 If (InStr(1, d, c, 1) > 0) Then
 c.Interior.Color = vbWhite
 Exit For
 End If
 Next
 Next
 For Each c In Worksheets("worksheet2").Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Cells
 For Each d In Worksheets("worksheet1").Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Cells
 c.Interior.Color = vbYellow
 If (InStr(1, d, c, 1) > 0) Then
 c.Interior.Color = vbWhite
 Exit For
 End If
 Next
 Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
End Sub
Worksheet 2:
Sub compare_cols()
 Dim myRng As Range
 Dim lastCell As Long
 'Get the last row
 Dim lastRow As Integer
 lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
 'Debug.Print "Last Row is " & lastRow
 Dim c As Range
 Dim d As Range
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 For Each c In Worksheets("worksheet2").Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Cells
 For Each d In Worksheets("worksheet3").Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Cells
 c.Font.Color = rgbRed
 If (InStr(1, d, c, 1) > 0) Then
 c.Font.Color = rgbBlack
 Exit For
 End If
 Next
 Next
 For Each c In Worksheets("worksheet3").Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Cells
 For Each d In Worksheets("worksheet2").Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Cells
 c.Interior.Color = vbRed
 c.Font.Color = rgbWhite
 If (InStr(1, d, c, 1) > 0) Then
 c.Interior.Color = vbWhite
 c.Font.Color = rgbBlack
 Exit For
 End If
 Next
 Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
End Sub
```

**Problems I'm having:**

- in comparing `worksheet1` and `worksheet2`, data that is not in `worksheet2` are highlighted green in `worksheet1`, and data that is not in `worksheet1` are highlighted yellow in `worksheet2`.
- some of the data in `worksheet2` for example are highlighted in yellow but are found in `worksheet1`, which shouldn’t happen. Then in comparing `worksheet2` and `worksheet3`, items that are not in `worksheet3` have a red colored font, in `worksheet2`, and items that are not in `worksheet2` are highlighted red with a white font, in `worksheet3`.
- data in `worksheet2` for example have a red colored font but are found in `worksheet3`, which shouldn’t happen.

Can you please tell me why my VBA code isn't working, or what I else I can do?

Comment: wouldn't this work for you? `I think so far when I do a vlookup the items that are in worksheet 1 and not worksheet 2 come up as #N/A are the discontinued items`. That is the fastest approach. Enter a `Vlookup` in worksheet2 (in a vacant column). Filter the #N/A, highlight them and copy to worksheet1 column A. What else d'you want?

Comment: @L42 it works as far as knowing which  items in worksheet 1 are discounted, but im still not able to find out which items in worksheet 2 are new items, the report is very large and I don't want to spend hours looking through it. then esp when a client needs it quickly.

Comment: we'd appreciate if you can provide a simple sample data and a sample desired result. If you are open to vba, show us what you've tried so far and specify where you're having difficulties.

Comment: @L42 for example Sheet 1 
Colum A Colum B
Item qty
100 25
456 10
102 34
203 55
104 20
105 88
106 99
107 1000
108 2500
109 400
111 5
200 550
225 200
264 4
558 31
278 55
and in sheet 2 
Column A Column B
Item qty
100 15
101 50
102 25
103 44
104 9000
105 200
106 25
107 55683
108 1000
109 444
110 57696
500 5454
554 566
664 23
700 34
888 55
300 28
some of the items in column A of sheet 1 are in column A of sheet 2. when I do a vlookup, to pull the qty from worksheet 2 in worksheet 1 I get

Comment: @L42i get Sheet 1 
Colum A Colum B
Item qty
100 15
456 #N/A
102 25
203 #N/A
104 9000
105 200
106 25
107 55683
108 1000
109 444
111 #N/A
200 #N/A
225 #N/A
264 #N/A
558 #N/A
278 #N/A
 these items in column A of worksheet 1 that have #N/A as qty are discounted items. but I still have items that are in worksheet 2 that are new items that aren't in worksheet 1 sheet 2 
Column A Column B
Item qty
100 15
101 50
102 25
103 44
104 9000
105 200
106 25
107 55683
108 1000
109 444
110 57696
500 5454
554 566
664 23
700 34
888 55
300 28

Comment: @L42its these items that are the new items that I want to highlight and put in worksheet 1 (the template) that I want to update. sorry I tired to do a screen shot but it didn't work.  I Would like to do a VBA if that a option but my problem is I never worked with VBA so im not sure what to do

Comment: i updated your post to help others better understand your question. I think what you want to accomplish can really be done only using `VBA`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this automatically - it's about using VBA. But you don't have any knowledge of it, so I will not give you ready VBA solution.

To achieve your goal you can use `Remove duplicates`. With this you will create list of unique items - this will be list of all items from workbook1 and workbook2. Later you can create column with `vlookup` function as you did before. If item was found you will get Qty as you wanted, if not you will get `#N/D` which you can highlight using conditional formatting.

I guess it should solve your problem without VBA.

Comment: Im learning excel vba for beginners,  from homeandlearn.org... so if you could post the vba solution id appreciate it, also if you know of any other books/sites I can learn intermediate to advanced vba ad well as any other computer coding/language,  id really like to learn more,  I know very little html, but id love to learn and master computer programming.  @lowak

Comment: @user3138463 Provide sample code of what you have done so far and what is the problem. Remember, do not ask for: "Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)"

Comment: I added the code,  any suggestions on my new problem, listed at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Would conditional formatting work for your needs? Here's a way to highlight cells that appear in another range (or don't appear, if you throw a **"not("** in the mix).

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/use-conditional-formatting-to-compare-lists-in-excel/

I hope it helps!

JSR

Comment: Conditional formating won't work b/c according to Excel 2007 you can't conditional format another column , range of cells in another worksheet.